# Why do we have an 'Unanswered' tab in two places?

Tags: discussion

Why do we have the 'Unanswered' tab on main tabs as well as as a subtab under 'Questions'?
See the screenshot below:

[image]

Suggesting to place a more common feature in main tabs, i.e. Privileges.

Comment: I've been staring at these sites for _years_ and that's the first time I noticed that :)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145033/the-unanswered-section-vs-the-unanswered-question-tab-a-critique

Answer (score 27, accepted):

They seem to be different filters.  The one on top seems to trim down to questions that don't have an *accepted* answer, but may still have posted answers. The one below shows questions that have no *posted* answers.

Comment: nice observation though

Comment: More to the point, the one on the top allows you to apply secondary filter/sort characteristics. "no answers" is just the default.

Answer (score 20):

Talk about being snow blind; that's the first time I noticed the redundancy. The filtering options are the same on each question list view: 'newest', 'frequent', 'votes', 'active', and 'unanswered'. This means you could zoom in to find unanswered questions in a variety of tags, a great way to dive into building up some points.

The redundancy is quite ... humorous, but I don't think we'd bolt on a check to see if we're already *looking* at 'unanswered' and not bother showing the filter in that case if it involved more than a trivial amount of work. If you're there, you know why you're there and (like many, I suspect) will not even notice it.

I'm going to have a look to see how easy that would be to correct, though -- it's such a minor thing.

Comment: If I remember correctly those links show two separate "unanswered" lists. Some questions appear on one list, and not the other. In addition, the "Unanswered" button contains a tab for "no answers", probably because it's version of "unanswered" is "no answers with upvotes". For what it's worth, I use the Button version a lot and would be upset if it went away and I had to start using the tab :)

Comment: Yeah, those two tabs use different criteria for what it means to be "unanswered". Because simply duplicating the filter just isn't confusing enough. :)

Answer (score 11):

I've wondered this for a while now. I recall looking into it once, and there are differences.

- The <kbd>Unanswered</kbd> button returns a list of posts with no upvoted answer, and can be sorted by "My Tags", Newest, Votes, or "No Answers"
- The "Unanswered" tab takes the list of questions you are currently viewing, filters it for questions with no answers, then sorted that by Votes and Views.

Personally I use the Unanswered button a lot, and almost never use the Tab. If SE removes or renames one of these, I would prefer it to be the tab version.

Comment: you are right... but i already got the right answer by @Cypher

Comment: I've noticed that the questions filtered by `questions?sort=unanswered` are sorted by votes, whereas the questions filtered by `unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers` is sorted by most recent activity.

Comment: @AhsanShah But Rachel, posted her longer answer a couple minutes after Cyppher, so she probably started writing it first.